# What do the various "Can Appear as" options do in the Character Pool creator?

Tags: xcom-2

In the character creator in the Character Pool, there are options for how characters appear:

[image]

1. Can Appear as Soldier
2. Can Appear as VIP
3. Can Appear as Dark VIP

What do these options do? If I don't select any of them, do my created characters never show up in any of my campaigns?

If I select "Can Appear as Soldier", does that mean that the character can be recruited either through the Avenger, or as a mission reward, or through the black market or Resistance HQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Can Appear as Soldier* allows for characters to potentially appear wherever there is an opportunity to recruit soldiers. This includes mission rewards.

*Can Appear as VIP* lets characters to appear as Resistance VIPs in the rescue missions given to you by the Spokesman. Once rescued, they can be either Engineers or Scientists.

*Can Appear as Dark VIP* can cause them to appear in Guerilla Ops as ADVENT VIPs, who can be captured or killed.

Comment: So if I don't select any of these options, my created character will never show up in any of my campaigns, as either a soldier, VIP, or Dark VIP?

Comment: As far as I know, they will not.